# Check if row is within a certain Time Limit

Tags: excel, vba

This is a Macro that checks if rows are older than 30 mins of NOW and clears them if they are not.
I am trying to change:

```
Loop Until > Lastrow
```

to instead loop only until it reaches the first row within 30 mins of Now (to reduce the amount of computation as the machine is struggling). I've tried variations on:

```
Loop Until .Cells(i, "A") > TimeLimit
```

But without luck. Any help much appreciated!
Context:

```
Lastrow = Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row

With ws1
i = 1
    TimeLimit = Time - TimeSerial(0, 30, 0)
        Do

                If .Cells(i, "A") < TimeLimit Then
                   .Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.ClearContents
                End If

            i = i + 1
        Loop Until i > Lastrow
    End With

    End Sub
```

Here's the timer code it needs to go into:

```
Sub Update()

    With Sheets("DATA")

        rw = .Cells(.rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1
        .Range(.Cells(rw, 1), .Cells(rw, 6342)).value = Sheets("DATA").Range("A7:IJZ7").value

    End With
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), "update"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Clear()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim TimeLimit As Date, ChkTIme As Date

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

Lastrow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

TimeLimit = Time - TimeSerial(0, 30, 0)
For i = 10 To Lastrow                    'Since your data starts from row 10
ChkTIme = CDate(ws1.Range("A" & i).Value)

     If ChkTIme < TimeLimit Then
               ws1.Rows(i).EntireRow.ClearContents
     Else: End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Also formatting col A to Time format will be good.

Comment: Try using it now it worked fine on my end can you post screenshot of the worksheet in your question.

Comment: I think I know why : my data starts at row 10 and there are used cells above that in other data formats. I'll try and reformat the sheet and  incorporate your code into the timer. Thanks again!

Comment: Works great! Thanks so much!  I need to incorporate it into my timer code now, do I need the option Explicit because that seems to stop the timer from working? (I've added the timer code into the question in case you feel like taking a look!)